# How to extract html between tags

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, xmllint

I need to extract HTML between two tags using Linux command.

For example: A html document can have multiple `<h2>` tags like below

```
<h2>
    <a id="id1" name="name1"></a>
    test1
</h2>
<h2>
    <a id="id2" name="name2"></a>
    test2
</h2>
```

I need to extract inner HTML of all `<h2>` as array and passed to other php script as a parameter.

Required output:

```
<a id="id1" name="name1"></a>
    test1
<a id="id2" name="name2"></a>
    test2
```

I tried below :

```
file='/var/www/html/docs/test/test.htm' 

tagHtml=$(grep "<h2>" $file )
tagHtml=$(echo $metadata_tobe_added | sed 's/<h2>//g' | sed 's/<\/h2>//g')
echo $tagHtml
php /var/www/html/test.php "$tagHtml"
```

But nothing working for me. I hope I've been able to make a clear  question. Please help me.

**UPDATE:**

I tried :

```
awk -F" *</?h2> *\n?" -v RS="^$" '{
for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)
   printf "%s", $i
}' $file
```

and i am getting below output which if fine.

```
<a id="id1" name="name1"></a>
test1
<a id="id2" name="name2"></a>
test2
```

Now, i want to get the output into array so that i can pass into the php script as a parameter.

Comment: Why not read the file in your PHP script and process the HTML using PHP?

Comment: I have lacks of files to process which can take more time if i do with php.

Answer (score -1):

You might try that :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while read line; do
        case $line in
            "<h2>") c=0
                    ;;
            "</h2>")c=1
                    ;;
                *)  if [[ c -eq 0 ]]; then
                        echo $line
                    fi
                    ;;
        esac
    done < $html_file
```

Hope it helps